# Image not shown on span inside button

Tags: html, css

In this link  it looks like a button

```
<div class="button-row">
    <a href="<% url('/') class="btn-link btn-blue mbright {!! t("profile.unsuscribe_button_yes") !!}<span class="arrow-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

The css

```
.button-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.arrow-right {
  background: url('#{$iconsImagesPath}black-right-arrow.png') no-repeat;
}
```

The image is not visible on the button , but I see it on the inspector, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Try to add a specific height value on this class `arrow-right` like `height:50px` or etc

Comment: Your span has no content, and I don’t see you assigning a width and height to it anywhere either - so how big did you expect it to be?

Comment: @JesperMartinez Since its an anchor link, it defaults to `inline`,  to set `height`, `width`, or `margin` you will need to set `display:block` or `display: inline-block`

Comment: @CBroe I think the bootstrap classes set width and height ?

Comment: @BrianPatterson Yeah! you're right I think I missed this line to put `display:block` haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put some min-height and min-width (or) height and width. since it is a inline element also no content inside.

Try below in your code

```
.arrow-right {
    background: url('#{$iconsImagesPath}black-right-arrow.png') no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Since you are using Bootstrap buttons, you are limited to the confines of the Bootstrap Button Classes.   I have seen that you can use the `<button>` element with an image tag inside, but I'm not sure if that still works in bootstrap 4.

Can you try the code I updated in my answer (using :before and two classes).

---

If this doesn't work, remove the other classes on your anchor tag and add width and height to .arrow-right.   Once you see the image, start adding classes until it disappears again,  then you know what you need to troubleshoot.

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-row">
  <a href="<% url('/') class="btn-link btn-blue mbright {!! t("profile.unsuscribe_button_yes") !!}
    <span class="arrow-right arrow-image"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.arrow-right:before {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position : center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.arrow-image:before {
  background-image: url('#{$iconsImagesPath}black-right-arrow.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is the ***empty span that has a background image***.

By default, ***the width and height of an empty span will be 0px***. This causes the image to get hidden.

The easy way to fix this problem is by assigning the height and width attributes to the span.

**Here is an example for making the background image of a span visible when the span is empty:**

```
<div class="button-row">
  <a href="link-url-here">

    <!-- Set span dimensions to 20x20 to make the background visible -->
    <!-- Also, disable background repetition to show the image only once -->

    <span class="arrow-right arrow-image" 
          style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    </span>

  </a>
</div>
```